# MySQL Error 2005: No such host is known 'name'

Tags: mysql, sql

После создания базы данных и добавления ее в созданную учетную запись, при вызове команды в командной строке:

```
mysqlsh -u 'название учетной записи' -p 'название базы данных'
```

появляется команда

> Please provide the password for 'название учетной записи@название базы данных':

и введения пароля, sql выдает ошибку:

> MySQL Error 2005: No such host is known 'название базы данных'

хотя она существует, это точно

Answer (score 0):

для утилиты -p необходимо вводить пароль, а не название базы данных, чтобы получить доступ к базе данных, можно воспользоваться более подробной командой: mysql( или mysqlsh, зависит от названия файла .exe) --user='название учетной записи' --password='пароль' --database='название базы данных'